# Flex Autocomplete Multiselect with Dynamic Data Hillel Coren

Tags: apache-flex, autocomplete, flex4, dynamic-data, multi-select

I am trying to add multiselect autocomplete in apache flex 4 with the [Hillel Coren component](http://hillelcoren.com/flex-autocomplete/documentation/).

It works great, but I can't get the multiple selection to work unless I set the arrayCollection statically as in #3.    I can type in the box to select a second item, but when I select nothing happens.

Does anyone have any ideas?  Here is the code.

MXML

```
<components:AdvancedAutoComplete id="autoComplete3" dataProvider="{ mainDataArrayCollection }" 
        labelField="name" matchType="word" 
        prompt="Choose your favorite Player 3" width="100%"
        selectedItemStyleName="facebook"
        allowMultipleSelection="true" showRemoveIcon="true" 
                                 />
```

Actionscript

```
private function dataHandler(event: ResultEvent) : void {
mainData = event.result.playerStats;

mainDataCollection = new XMLListCollection(mainData);


    // #1
var resultArray:Array = mainDataCollection.toArray(); 
mainDataArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(resultArray);

   // #2
mainDataArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
for each ( var xml:XML in mainData ) {
        var playerObj = new Object;
        playerObj.name = xml.player;
        playerObj.id = xml.id.toString();
            mainDataArrayCollection.addItem(playerObj);

}

    //  #3
   //  Only method that will allow multiple select.
mainDataArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(
            [
                { "name":"Pujols Albert", "id":"1" },
                { "name":"Homer Orange", "id":"2" }
            ] );
```

Comment: You're sure that AC #1,2,3 are identical before you use them?

Comment: Actually 1,2 and 3 are not identical before I use the.  But number 2 I have put an if statement in to limit it to 2 players.

Comment: I think it is strange that the component works and is populated by the Array Collection, but I can't add multiple selections.